# How can I put the ui.bootstrap.progressbar in my angular datatables ajax

Tags: angularjs, ajax, angular-datatables

Can anyone help me adding some loading bar while datatable is getting data from the database? This is my code. what should I need to add for the progressbar will start loading while getting data then progress bar will remove after all data has been loaded to the data table.

```js
var msgTemp = angular.module("tableLOVApp", ['datatables', 'ngResource', 'datatables.bootstrap','ui.bootstrap'])
 .controller('tableLOVCtrl', tableLOVCtrl);

tableLOVCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$resource', '$http', '$compile', '$timeout', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder', 'DTColumnDefBuilder'];

function tableLOVCtrl($scope, $resource, $http, $compile, $timeout, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder){
 var vm = this;

 vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('ajax', {
     url : 'msgTemplate/msgTemplateList.json',
     type : 'GET',
     data : function(d){
      d.sortColumn = d.columns[d.order[0].column].data;
      d.order = d.order[0].dir;
      d.filter = d.search.value;
     }
    })
    .withOption('createdRow', function(row, data, dataIndex) {
                   $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
               })
    .withDataProp(function(json){
     json.recordsTotal = json.data.length == 0 ? 0 : json.data[0].count;
     json.recordsFiltered = json.data.length == 0 ? 0 : json.data[0].count;
     return json.data;
    })
    /*.withOption('language',{loadingRecords: "Please wait - loading..."})*/
    .withOption('fnRowCallback', rowCallback)
    .withOption('serverSide', true)
    .withOption('processing', true)
    .withDisplayLength(10)
    .withOption('scrollY', '362px')
    .withBootstrap()
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
 
 vm.dtColumns = [
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('messageCd').withTitle('Message Code'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('keyword').withTitle('Keyword'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('messageType').withTitle('Message Type')
          ];
```

```html
<div ng-app="tableLOVApp" ng-controller="tableLOVCtrl as showCase">
  <div>
    <table datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" dt-instance="showCase.dtInstance" class="table row-border hover"></table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[This is what I want to do...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWZyc.png)